# python type 'list' doesn't have expected attribute 'tolist'

Tags: python, list

i am coding python in PyCharm and it is giving me this warning:

```
type 'list' doesn't have expected attribute 'tolist'
```

however I have declared my variable list, and here is my code:

```
...
my_list = []
big_list = []
i= 0
count = 0

while i < len(data):
    if data[i][3] < 0:
        i += 1
        continue
    my_list.append([data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], data[i][3]])

    if i == len(df) - 1:
        count += 1
        self.myfancyfunction(my_list, count)
        big_list.append(my_list)

    elif i < len(data) - 1 and data[i][3] != data[i + 1][3]:
        count += 1
        self.myfancyfunction(my_list, count)
        big_list.append(my_list)
        my_list = []

        cluster += 1
    i += 1
```

in the two instances of `self.myfancyfunction(my_list, count)`, the `my_list` variable is underlined and shows the above error.

Could you please help to fix this?

### update

here is my fancy function:

```
def myfancyfunction(self, array_ls, count):
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {}
    array_ls = np.asarray(array_ls)
    array_ls = array_ls[:, 2].astype(int)

    self.info_ids.append(array_ls.tolist())

    sys.stdout.flush()

    with open('myfile.txt', "r") as myfile:        
        for line in myfile:            
            if int(line.split()[0]) in array_ls:

                for element in line.split()[1:]:

                    key = element.split(":")[0]
                    value = float(element.split(":")[1])

                    if key in self.reference:
                        if not str(key) in dict1:
                            dict1[str(key)] = 1
                            dict2[str(key)] = value
                        else:
                            dict1[str(key)] += 1
                            dict2[str(key)] += value

    self.info_freq.append(dict1)
    self.info_vals.append(dict2)
```

I am inside a class and have a couple of functions.

Comment: This code makes no sense. Are you inside a class? Why are there self methods. Wha does fancy function do? Presumably call tolist

Comment: that thing is already a list, why are you converting that to `tolist`?